# CacheLoader is not getting called while trying to find an entity using GemfireRepository

Tags: spring-boot, caching, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

`CacheLoader` is not getting called while trying to find an entity using `GemfireRepository`.

As a solution, I am using `Region<K,V>` for looking up, which is calling `CacheLoader`. So wanted to know whether there is any restriction for *Spring Data* `Repository` which doesn't allow `CacheLoader` to be called when entry is not present in the cache.

And, is there any other alternative? Because I have one more scenario where my cache key is combination of id1 & id2 and I want to get all entries **based on id1**. And if there is no entry present in cache, then it will call `CacheLoader` to load all entries from Cassandra store.

Comment: Note, loading all entries from Cassandra (or another Data Store) from a `CacheLoader` is quite another thing.  Possible, but...

Answer (score 1):

There are no limitations nor restrictions in SDG when using the SD Repository abstraction (and SDG's Repository extension) that would prevent a `CacheLoader` from being invoked so long as the `CacheLoader` was properly registered on the target `Region`.  Once control is handed over to GemFire/Geode to complete the data access operation (CRUD), it is out of SDG's hands.

However, you should know that GemFire/Geode only invokes `CacheLoaders` on **gets** (i.e. `Region.get(key)` operations), never on (OQL) queries.  OQL queries are invoked from derived query methods or custom, user-defined query methods using `@Query` annotated methods declared in the application *Repository* interface.

> NOTE: See Apache Geode [CacheLoader Javadoc](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheLoader.html) and [User Guide](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/19/developing/outside_data_sources/how_data_loaders_work.html) for more details.

For a simple [`CrudRepository.findById(key)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-) call, the call stack follows from...

1. [`SimplyGemfireRepository.findById(key)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.3.0.M4/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/support/SimpleGemfireRepository.java#L143-L150)
2. [`GemfireTemplate.get(key)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.3.0.M4/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.java#L161-L173)
3. And then, [`Region.get(key)`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#get-java.lang.Object-) (from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.3.0.M4/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.java#L168)).

By way of example, and to illustrate this behavior, I added the [`o.s.d.g.repository.sample.RepositoryDataAccessOnRegionUsingCacheLoaderIntegrationTests`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/master/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/repository/sample/RepositoryDataAccessOnRegionUsingCacheLoaderIntegrationTests.java) to the SDG test suite as part of [DATAGEODE-308](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGEODE-308).  You can provide additional feedback in this JIRA ticket, if necessary.

Cheers!